# Check if string is empty, then continue

Tags: c, shell, scanf, strcmp

I'm creating a very basic shell. When the user hits enter without typing any commands, the program should go to next line and continue.

If the user type any command, the program should print a text message.

I'm having issues with the empty string condition.

Tried `strcmp()` with another char array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char input[256];
    char str[4] = {"exit"};

    do
    {
        printf("CSC327> ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", &input);
        if(getchar() == '\n')
            continue;       
        if(strcmpi(input, str))
            printf("Command not found!\n");
    }while(strcmpi(input,str));

    printf("\nGoodbye.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've made a number of basic mistakes -- you might want to go back and read the first few chapters of your C textbook again. (1) `str` isn't big enough. (2) `strcmp` doesn't work like that -- you've got the sense reversed. (3) If you want to find empty lines, you want to compare against the string `""`, not the string `"exit"`. (4) You don't want `&` with that `scanf`. (5) You probably want `fgets`, not `scanf`. (6) If you do use `scanf`, you do need to get rid of the `\n` it didn't read, but if you do a `continue` when you find one you'll skip everything.

Comment: In answer to your specific question, in general, the way to ignore blank lines is to (a) first strip leading and trailing whitespace if necessary (which you have to do anyway), then (b) see if what you're left with is an empty string, which you can detect by doing `if(strcmp(input, "") == 0)` or just `if(*input == '\0')`.  Or, I often find it easier to go to the next step, which is breaking the line up into whitespace-separated words, and then seeing if the number of words I've found is 0.

Comment: Once you get it working, another thing to worry about if the user types a line longer than will fit in `input`.

Comment: I did very basic C back in first year of university. I took a course now about operating systems and i had to to this basic shell to build on later on. Got it working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: More generally speaking (not so much in your current example, but for your way forward), the `*scanf()` function family is intended for reading "known good", *formatted* input. It's error recovery capabilities (when interactive *human* input does not match the specified format) are somewhat limited, and the usual approach is to `fgets()` whole lines of input and then parse them in memory (with e.g. `strchr()`, `strtol()`, `strtok()` or similar as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

First the working version of code here!.

---

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_strcmp(char *a, char *b)
{

    while(*a == *b){
        a++;
        b++;
    }

    ///check line ending
    if (*a == '\n' && *b=='\0')
        return 0;//are equal    

    return 1;       
}

int main(void)
{

    char input[256]; //Array of characters for user input
    int flag = 1;

    do
    {

        printf("CSC327> ");
        fgets(input, 256, stdin); //Read user input

        if(*input == '\n')
            continue;       

        if(my_strcmp(input, "exit")){ //Compare temp with 'exit' case insensitive
            printf("Command not found!\n"); 
        }

        else{
            printf("Ok! Exiting\n");
            flag=0;
        }
    }while(flag); 


    printf("\nGoodbye.");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Main problem is in `strcmp()` function. I prefer to write a simple version under the name of `my_strcmp()` to work exactly in this question.

Consider last character of string source and destination. 
source ending is `'\n'` and destination is `'\0'`.

An ugly version to do this comparison used here. `my_strcmp()` can be very better but now just enough.

You call `strcmp()` two times, by using a flag one of them can be remove.

As  Steve Summit say at [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403454/check-if-string-is-empty-then-continue/58404563#comment103152178_58403454) we can use `if(*input == '\n') continue;` instead of your way.

***Related link about writing a shell***

- [Tutorial Write a Shell in C](https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/) by Stephen Brennan, [GitHub](https://github.com/brenns10/lsh/blob/master/src/main.c)
- [Making your own Linux Shell in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/making-linux-shell-c/)
- [Want to build a simple shell? Here’s how you do it.](https://medium.com/@nickteixeira/want-to-build-a-simple-shell-heres-how-you-do-it-75890647bae8)

In [brenns shell](https://github.com/brenns10/lsh/blob/master/src/main.c#L182) Consider line 187 `if (position >= bufsize)` as  Steve Summit say in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403454/check-if-string-is-empty-then-continue/58404563#comment103152457_58403454) you must handle a situation if user input a larger buffer input.

- Take a look at [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) that guide me to find out why builtin `strcmp()` not work properly because of different line ending 10 vs. 0.

**Edit**

- Use '\n' instead of 10 as suggested in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403454/check-if-string-is-empty-then-continue/58404563#comment103160799_58404563)
- `my_strcmp()` not work as case intensive compare I will improve it soon.
- `fgets()` add `\n` line feed character at the end of inputted string. i.e: input[last]= `'\n'`. But `char s[] = "test"` adds `'\0'`
  at the end of string s. For this we cant compare simply these string with library functions for example strcmp and others.
- change this character and use library function [`strcasecmp()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rtref/strcasecmp.htm) 
  By this do while loop can be rewrite

```
do
    {

        printf("CSC327> ");
        fgets(input, 256, stdin); //Read user input
        //fgets add \n at the end of string
        /// "salam" add \0 at end of string
        ///change last char
        input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';

        //printf("len: %ld", strlen(input));

        if(*input == '\n')
            continue;       

        if(strcasecmp(input, "exit")){ //Compare temp with 'exit' case insensitive
            printf("Command not found!\n"); 
        }

        else{
            printf("Ok! Exiting\n");
            flag=0;
        }
    }while(flag); 


    printf("\nGoodbye.");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be clearer to use `'\n'` instead of `10` in your `my_strcmp()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a string is empty, just use

`int lenght = strlen(your_string)`

The length of the string is returned. If it is 0, the string is empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
char input[256]; //Array of characters for user input
char temp[4]; //Array of 4 characters for getting the first 4 characters of input 
do
{
    printf("CSC327>");
    fgets(input, 256, stdin); //Read user input
    strncpy(temp, input, 4); //Get first 4 characters of input
    if(strlen(input) == 1) //Determine if input is empty
        continue;   
    if(strcmpi(temp, "exit")) //Compare temp with 'exit' case insensitive
        printf("Command not found!\n");
}
while(strcmpi(temp, "exit")); 
printf("\nGoodbye.");
return 0;
}//main ends
```